# UITextView like iPhone Notes application

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I am trying to recreate the Notes application. So far I got the following:

```
    textView                 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25.0, 30.0, 295.0, 214.0)];
textView.delegate        = self;
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textView.font            = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Thin" size:19.0];  
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

The thing I dont know is how they were able to put the date on top like a header (it is within the UIScrollView that is obvious). Also under every text there is a line where did that came from.

Does someone have an idea or a sample project I can take a look at?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at this: [Stuff you learn from reverse-engineering Notes.app](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/03/stuff-you-learn-from-reverse-engineering-notes-app/)

Comment: Absolutely brilliant... no idea why this article didnt pop up on my endless google hunt.